# Java Do X IF catch was not called from a try loop

Tags: java

Not sure if this has already been answered, but.

I know that in java there is the try, catch and finally blocks, but is there one which is only called if try has no errors/exceptions?

Currently after stating the command that needs to be run, I'm setting a boolean to true, and after the try and catch block, the program checks for if the boolean is true.

I'm pretty sure that there is a much simpler way, help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your code *after* the `try...catch` block and return in the `catch`:

```
boolean example() {
    try {
        //dostuff
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This would also work if you put the `return true` at the end of the `try` block as the code would jump to the `catch` on error and not execute the rest of the `try`.

```
void example() {
    try {
        //do some stuff that may throw an exception
        //do stuff that should only be done if no exception is thrown
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no block called only if no exceptions were raised.

The `catch` block is called if there were exceptions, `finally` is called regardless.

As stated, you can *emulate* such a beast with something like:

```
bool completed = false;
try {
    doSomeStuff();
    completed = true;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    handleException();
} finally {
    regularFinallyHandling();
    if (completed) {
        thisIsTheThingYouWant();
    }
}
```

but there's nothing built into the language itself that provides this functionality.

Comment: Thanks, this was what i was doing before.